# Android got message Error in Display android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException

Tags: android, multithreading, exception, view

My simple Query DB program via JSON to PHP - MySQL DB.

I got a messages :
Error in Display!android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

when I did Query.

I have tried and modified the program from using EditText to input the branchname, the result of the Query to php via JSON, is ok.

But after changed from EditText to Spindle, I got that message as above.

Could anyone help on this ? Thanks a lot.

> ```
> public class Querybybranch extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
>       private ProgressDialog pDialog;
>       JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
>
>       Spinner spinner3;
>
>       Button submit5;    
>       TextView tv5;      // TextView to show the result of MySQL query 
>
>       String branchname = null ;   
>
>       String returnString;   // to store the result of MySQL query after decoding JSON
>
>
>       private static String url_queryname = "http://vciwhereabout.ddns.net/waboutbybranch.php";
>
>       private static String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";      
>
>       /** Called when the activity is first created. */
>       @Override
>       public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
>     {
>        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
>        .detectDiskReads().detectDiskWrites().detectNetwork() 
>        .penaltyLog().build());
>           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>           setContentView(R.layout.activity_jsonuse5);
>
>           Spinner spinner3 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner3);
>
>           ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter3 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
>           R.array.branchtypearray, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
>
>           adapter3.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
>
>           spinner3.setAdapter(adapter3);
>
>           addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection();
>
>           branchname = spinner3.getSelectedItem().toString();
>
>           submit5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnsubmit5);
>           tv5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.showresult5);
>             submit5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
>           {        
>            public void onClick(View v) {
>
>                new AttemptQueryBranchName().execute();     
>
>           } 
>
>          });
>         }
>
>       public void addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection() {
>
>           spinner3 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner3);   
>           spinner3.setOnItemSelectedListener(new CustomOnItemSelectedListener());
>         }
>
>         public void addListenerOnButton() {
>
>           spinner3 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner3);
>           spinner3.setOnItemSelectedListener(new CustomOnItemSelectedListener()); 
>         }             
>
>
>   class AttemptQueryBranchName extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
>
>       @Override
>       protected void onPreExecute() {
>           super.onPreExecute();
>           pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Querybybranch.this);
>           pDialog.setMessage("Attempting query...");
>           pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
>           pDialog.setCancelable(true);
>           pDialog.show();
>       }
>
>       @Override
>       protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
>           ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
>
>           postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("branchname", branchname));
>
> //            postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("branchname", branchname.getText().toString()));
>
>           String response = null;
>
>           try{
>
>               response = CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost(
>                       "http://vciwhereabout.ddns.net/waboutbybranch.php", postParameters);
>
>           String result = response.toString();  
>
>             //parse json data
>                try{
>
>                 returnString = "";    
>
>                 JSONObject object = new JSONObject(result);
>                 JSONArray jArray = object.getJSONArray("posts");
>
>                        for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
>                           JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);     
>
>                           Log.i("log_tag","post_id: "+json_data.getInt("post_id")+
>                                        ", username: "+json_data.getString("username")+
>                                        ", name: "+json_data.getString("name")+
>                                        ", division: "+json_data.getString("division")+
>                                        ", branchname: "+json_data.getString("branchname")+
>                                        ", fdate: "+json_data.getString("fdate")+
>                                        ", tdate: "+json_data.getString("tdate")+
>                                        ", ftime: "+json_data.getString("ftime")+
>                                        ", ttime: "+json_data.getString("ttime")+
>                                        ", type_name: "+json_data.getString("type_name")+
>                                        ", note: "+json_data.getString("note")+
>                                        ", custbranch: "+json_data.getString("custbranch")+
>                                        ", custname: "+json_data.getString("custname")+
>                                        ", custaddr: "+json_data.getString("custaddr")+
>                                        ", custcity: "+json_data.getString("custcity")
>                                    );
>                                //Get an output to the screen
>
>                                returnString += "\n" + "Post ID  :" + "\t" + json_data.getString("post_id")
>                                + "\n" + "User-id       :" + json_data.getString("username")
>                                + "\n" + "Name        :"  + "\t" + json_data.getString("name")
>                                + "\n" + "Division      :"  + "\t" + json_data.getString("division")
>                                + "\n" + "HO/Branch :" + json_data.getString("branchname") 
>                                + "\n" + "From Date :" + json_data.getString("fdate") 
>                                + "\n" + "To Date     :" + json_data.getString("tdate") 
>                                + "\n" + "From Time :" + json_data.getString("ftime") 
>                                + "\n" + "To Time     :" + json_data.getString("ttime")
>                                + "\n" + "Req.Type: :" + json_data.getString("type_name")
>                                + "\n" + "Note :" + json_data.getString("note") 
>                                + "\n" + "Cust/Br. :" + json_data.getString("custbranch") 
>                                + "\n" + "Cust.Name:" + json_data.getString("custname") 
>                                + "\n" + "Address :" + json_data.getString("custaddr") 
>                                + "\n" + "City       :" + json_data.getString("custcity")+ "\n" 
>                                + "------------------------" + "\n" ;
>
>                                                            }
>                    }
>
>                catch(JSONException e){
>                        Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
>                        returnString += "No Records found for this Query" ;
>                                       } 
>
>                try{
>                 tv5.setText(returnString);
>                    }
>                catch(Exception e){
>                 Log.e("log_tag","Error in Display!" + e.toString());;          
>                        }
>                   }
>                catch (Exception e) {
>                    Log.e("log_tag","Error in http connection!!" + e.toString());
>
>                  }
>           if (response == "null")  { 
>               Toast.makeText(Querybybranch.this, "branchname not found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
>            }
>               else {}
>
>           return null;
> //            return response;
>
>   }
>
>       protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
>           // dismiss the dialog once product deleted
>           pDialog.dismiss();
>           if (file_url != null) {
>               Toast.makeText(Querybybranch.this, file_url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
>                }
> //                else {
> //                    Toast.makeText(Querynameentry21.this, "User not found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
> //                }
>           }
>       }
>
>     @Override
>   public void onClick(View v) {
>       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
>
>   }
>   }
> ```

And this is the spindle arrays :

```
> <string-array name="branchtypearray">
>         <item>HO VCI</item>
>         <item>Cabang Jakarta 1</item>
>         <item>Cabang Jakarta 2</item>
>         <item>Cabang Bandung</item>
>         <item>Cabang Semarang</item>
>         <item>Cabang Surabaya</item>
>         <item>Cabang Denpasar</item>
>         <item>Cabang REGIONAL BARAT</item>
>         <item>Cabang REGIONAL TIMUR</item>
>         <item>Pabrik</item>
>         <item>HO 3C</item>
>     </string-array>
```

Plus the layout of the activity :

```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <LinearLayout
> xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>     android:orientation="vertical" >
> 
> <!-- Cust/Branch Namelabel -->
>     <TextView
>         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
>         android:textColor="#43bd00"
>         android:textSize="20sp"
>         android:text="Branch Name to be Query" />
>         
>     <Spinner
>         android:id="@+id/spinner3"
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:entries="@array/branchtypearray"
>         />
>     <Button
>         android:id="@+id/btnsubmit5"
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:text="Submit"
>         android:layout_gravity="center"
>          />  <LinearLayout
>                 android:id="@+id/box"
>                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
>                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>                 android:layout_margin="1dp"
>                 android:orientation="vertical"
>                 android:padding="1dp" >
>                 
>              <ImageView
>                 android:id="@+id/imageView1"
>                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>                 android:src="@drawable/logo3s" 
>                 android:gravity="center_horizontal"
>                 />                           
>          
>            <ScrollView
>     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>     android:lines="20"
>     android:layout_height="390dip" >        
>            <TextView
>         android:id="@+id/showresult5"
>         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:singleLine="false"
>         android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
>   
>         android:paddingBottom="2dip"
>         android:paddingLeft="45dip"
>         android:textColor="#5d5d5d"
>       />
>          </ScrollView>          </LinearLayout>   </LinearLayout>
```

The output screen is just 'blank' and nothing appeared.

PHP and DB is ok and tested with the good result, when I used EditText (change to  "spindle" and got the problem).

Comment: Move the `tv5.setText()` call to `onPostExecute()`.

Comment: @Mike M, thanks a lot. I moved it as you suggested and it is working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After moved the below statement on postExecute as suggested by Mike M , the problem solved. Thanks a lot Mike M.

```
> try{
>                 tv5.setText(returnString);
>                    }
>                catch(Exception e){
>                 Log.e("log_tag","Error in Display!" + e.toString());;


                   }
```